# PHP Variable inside PHP -> Echo -> Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

so I have issue I don't even know how to tell it. But here it is.

```
//Coupon Code?
if($row['coupon'] == null or $row['2email'] == 'Confirmed')
{
echo '<td>
<input type="text" onKeyup="trackChange(this.value)" id="myInput">
<script type="text/javascript">
var dID = <?php echo $dID; ?>;
function wait(ms){
var start = new Date().getTime();
var end = start;
while(end < start + ms) {
 end = new Date().getTime();
}
}

function trackChange(value)
{
window.open("/functions.php?cCODE="+value+"&ccID="+dID)

}
</script>
</td>';
```

All I need is to get "user ID" from $dID=$row['ID']; but as it seems It just echo out that to the result and don't do any job. How can I get php variable inside php -> inside Echo -> inside Javascript.

I thought by going other way but I need text box and then submit to url. But I can't seem to get it working. Only 1 request at a time and I need 2. (User ID, and text to text box response)

```
echo " <td><form action= functions.php?cID=  method= 'post'><input 
type='hidden' name='cID' value=$dID />
<input type= 'submit' name= 'type' value= Confirm></form></td>";
```

So I can't get them both to submit that. Only found a way inside javascript.

[Picture of text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrERO.png)

Comment: You can't have `<?php echo $dID; ?>` inside a PHP echo. [Check out the PHP manual about string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: also don't mix php + js - don't use inline js or inline css. It's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Comment: I can't use directly cause then it just adds to the URL address "<?php echo $dID; ?>;" all of this

Comment: You have to build solid understanding of Server - Client model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use string concatenation (using the `.` character) to insert a variable into your string. Like this:

```
echo '
[...]
<script type="text/javascript">
var dID = ' . $dID . ';
function wait(ms){
[...]
';
```

---

A `.` will concatenate two strings together. For example:

```
echo 'hello ' . ' world'
```

You can also insert a variable directly into a string, if you use double quotes. Single quotes do not allow you to do this:

```
$text = "world";
echo "hello $text";
```

In general, you should wrap your variables in curly brackets (`{` and `}`)

```
$text = "world";
echo "hello {$text}";
```

Comment: No need for `echo` when concatenating a variable.

Comment: to concat with echo you do: `echo $var1. ' ' .$var2;` - not echo inside echo

Comment: I get error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in when adding var dID = ' . echo $dID . '; line. As thisguyhastwothumbs mentioned I can do that. But I get latest entry from table - 122 ID, it seems that it don't care about PHP lining.

Comment: Sorry all; the additional echo in the concatenation was my poor editing of the original code. I've corrected that in the edit.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Shoot, thanks! Corrected now. I thought this would just be a quick answer to give, and it's resulted in these oversights. :/

Answer (score 0):

**You can just concatenate the variable there**
To concatenate use **.**

```
 if($row['coupon'] == null or $row['2email'] == 'Confirmed')
 {
    echo "<td>
    <input type='text' onKeyup='trackChange(this.value)' id='myInput'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var dID = '".$dID."'
    function wait(ms){
          var start = new Date().getTime();
          var end = start;
          while(end < start + ms) {
              end = new Date().getTime();
              }
         }

    function trackChange(value)
       {
          window.open('/functions.php?cCODE='+value+'&ccID='+dID)

       }
        </script>
         </td>";
```

Comment: You need to keep track of your quotes. A double quote inside a string wrapped in double quotes _ends_ the string. This would throw syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: No, you actually didn't. You still close and open the string on every single html attribute and in your window.open.

Comment: You can try that code you won't get any error there I just used double quote inside single quote no problem there.@MagnusEriksson

Comment: Please read your own code. You have _double quotes_ inside _double quotes_. Check here: `echo "<td><input type="text.. ` <== You _end_ the string right before `text`, and that's just one of many places you're doing it.

Comment: I got it Thank you @MagnusEriksson